# How can use URLSession?

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsurlsession

```
import UIKit
struct Headline {


var id : Int
var title : String
var text : String
var image : String
var color: UIColor!


}
var headlines = [
            [
                Headline(id: 1, title: "Mazda 3 2.0", text: "Price: 9800000000", image: "", color: UIColor.red),
                Headline(id: 2, title: "Mazda 3 2.0", text: "Price: 9600000000", image: "", color: UIColor.blue),
                Headline(id: 3, title: "Mazda 3 2.0", text: "Price: 9000000000", image: "", color: UIColor.black)
            ],
            [
                Headline(id: 4, title: "Mazda 3 1.5", text: "Price: 8000000000", image: "", color: UIColor.red),
                Headline(id: 5, title: "Mazda 3 1.5", text: "Price: 8500000000", image: "", color: UIColor.blue),
                Headline(id: 6, title: "Mazda 3 1.5", text: "Price: 8700000000", image: "", color: UIColor.black)
            ]


    ]

class CarTableViewController: UITableViewController {


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return headlines.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return headlines[section].count
}

let headerTitles = ["Mazda Version 2", "Mazda Version 1.5"]
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section < headerTitles.count {
        return headerTitles[section]
    }

    return nil
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)

    let headline = headlines[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = headline.title
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = headline.text
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.backgroundColor = headline.color
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: headline.image)


    return cell
}

}
```

I had 3 link: https://f1.media.brightcove.com/8/1078702682/1078702682_6004950245001_6004956161001-vs.jpg?pubId=1078702682&videoId=6004956161001
https://c.ndtvimg.com/2019-08/k8519lf8_bugatti-centodieci-unveiled-at-pebble-beach-car-show_625x300_17_August_19.jpg
https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/17XG3/s1/bugatti-la-voiture-noire-leaves-geneva.jpg

How to use URLSesstion set image for tableviewcontroll ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading/Downloading image from URL on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `cellForRowAt`, set the `image` for `urlString` like,

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //rest of the code...
    if let url = URL(string: headline.image) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.imageView?.image = image
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Edit:**

Update the `headlines` `array` to,

```
var headlines = [
    [
        Headline(id: 1, title: "Mazda 3 2.0", text: "Price: 9800000000", image: "https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/17XG3/s1/bugatti-la-voiture-noire-leaves-geneva.jpg", color: UIColor.red),
        Headline(id: 2, title: "Mazda 3 2.0", text: "Price: 9600000000", image: "https://c.ndtvimg.com/2019-08/k8519lf8_bugatti-centodieci-unveiled-at-pebble-beach-car-show_625x300_17_August_19.jpg", color: UIColor.blue),
        Headline(id: 3, title: "Mazda 3 2.0", text: "Price: 9000000000", image: "https://f1.media.brightcove.com/8/1078702682/1078702682_6004950245001_6004956161001-vs.jpg?pubId=1078702682&videoId=6004956161001", color: UIColor.black)
    ],
    [
        Headline(id: 4, title: "Mazda 3 1.5", text: "Price: 8000000000", image: "https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/17XG3/s1/bugatti-la-voiture-noire-leaves-geneva.jpg", color: UIColor.red),
        Headline(id: 5, title: "Mazda 3 1.5", text: "Price: 8500000000", image: "https://c.ndtvimg.com/2019-08/k8519lf8_bugatti-centodieci-unveiled-at-pebble-beach-car-show_625x300_17_August_19.jpg", color: UIColor.blue),
        Headline(id: 6, title: "Mazda 3 1.5", text: "Price: 8700000000", image: "https://f1.media.brightcove.com/8/1078702682/1078702682_6004950245001_6004956161001-vs.jpg?pubId=1078702682&videoId=6004956161001", color: UIColor.black)
    ]    
]
```

Comment: this isn't the correct approach cells are re-used and this code may download the same image many times even at the same time

Comment: I want each cell to be a different image :(

Comment: @TrầnNgọcTân Have you added the images in your Headline objects? If yes, it will fetch the image for each headline.image.

Comment: i foget delete iamges in obj headline, now, i want get 3 image from 3 link, how can i get this, pls help me ty

Comment: Where have you stored the image urls? First update the code. And the code I provided will work for each cell. Atleast give it a try first  and see what error are you getting.

Comment: 3 url in question, i updated code but i dont know to where URL

Comment: Here `Headline(id: 1, title: "Mazda 3 2.0", text: "Price: 9800000000", image: "", color: UIColor.red)` the image is empty string. Instead add the actual urlString in all these.

Comment: i tried, no error, but when running the app the image does not display